# Implementing "View as HTML" for Word and PDF documents on an intranet

Tags: ms-office

I am looking for a way to implement "View as HTML" (as seen in e.g. GMail) for Microsoft Office and Adobe PDF documents stored in an intranet. Can anyone recommend approaches for this?

The intranet consists of multiple .NET sites, so I would prefer a .NET library (one that doesn't launch MS Word on the server) for this capability, but any kind of arrangement is welcome.